# Deduce probability density function from integrals on $N$ bounded regions

Tags: probability-distributions, geometric-measure-theory

I stumbled upon this problem.

Suppose you have an unknown probability density function on the two dimensional real plane, $f(x,y)$
Suppose you have three distinct points $P_1, P_2, P_3$ on the plane and that, for each triplet $(r_1, r_2, r_3)$ you know the integral of $f$ on the regions bounded by circles centered in $P_1,P_2,P_3$ and radii $r_1,r_2,r_3$. These integrals are given by the functions $g_1(r_1), g_2(r_2), g_3(r_3)$.
How can I derive $f(x,y)$ from $g_1,g_2$ and $g_3$ ?
What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for $g1,g2,g3$ to be coherent between them and with a generic probability density function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot derive $f(x,y)$ from $g_1$, $g_2$, $g_3$; they contain less information than $f$.

Without loss of generality, let $P_1=(-1,0)$, $P_2=(1,0)$ and $P_3=(0,a)$, and consider the four points $P_{\rho\sigma}=(\rho x,\sigma y)$ with $\rho,\sigma\in\{-1,1\}$ and with arbitrary $x,y\in\mathbb R$. With respect to each of $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$, these four points form two pairs of equidistant points. We can move probability from $P_{++}$ to $P_{+-}$ and make up for it my moving the same probability from $P_{--}$ to $P_{-+}$. This changes $f$, but none of $g_1$, $g_2$ and $g_3$. (In case you didn't mean to allow point probability masses, you can do the same thing with a bump function in the vicinity of the points $P_{\sigma\rho}$.)

Comment: Wow, impressive solution!

Comment: I see that with $k=4$ and $P_{4}=(x_{4},y_{4})$, with $x_{4} \neq 0$, the balance in your example would break and the associated $g_{4}$ would change. So further question: under suitable conditions on the $P_{k}$ points and the associated $g_{k}$, with $k>3$, would it possible to deduce the distribution?

Comment: @user259428: My intuition would be that no finite number of one-dimensional distributions would fix the two-dimensional distribution, but I don't off the top of my head see how it could be proved for $4$. The required rearrangements could be prohibitively complicated. Perhaps some form of fixed-point argument could work. Or my intution could be wrong -- after all it's possible to represent all three-dimensional functions by a countable superposition of one-dimensional functions (using spherical harmonics), which also seems strange at first sight. But you want finitely, not just countably many.

Comment: I have the feeling your analogy is right. In our case, if the distribution has finite moments and cross-moments for any order, then the statement about the countable infinity would be sensible.

Comment: Let's put a variation on the problem, closer to what I actually found (see [link](https://tech.zalando.com/jobs/65946/?gh_jid=65946), which actually has unreasonable assumptions that I'm trying to change in order to solve a problem that makes sense). If I actually have a finite length curve $C_{1}$ (piecewise differentiable), another finite length and piecewise differentiable curve $C_{2}$ and a point $P$ that doesn't lie on $C_{1}$ or $C_{2}$, and the associated functions of the distances from the curves $g_{1}$, $g_{2}$ and the distance from the point $P$, $g_{3}$, then?

Comment: I guess your dimensionality reasoning still applies: denote $f(x,y)$ as the "true" probability function. If it has finite cross-moments for any order, then the integrals on the bounded regions are a linear function of $f$. I don't know much about infinite dimensional vector spaces (gotta learn them yet), but obviously all the $g_{k}$ are linear in $f$, so we need countably many independent regions.